# jquery bind value to html select tag

Tags: jquery, html

can anyone help with the following:

I have an ajax method that calls server side code and retrieves list of books and loads into html table.

```
   function LoadData(data) {

  var tbody = $("#accountTable > tbody").html("");
  var thead = $("#accountTable > thead").html("");

   var rowHead = "<tr>"
                + "<th style='border-bottom-style:dotted;border-bottom-width:1px;font-size:10px'>Name</th>"
                + "<th style='border-bottom-style:dotted;border-bottom-width:1px;font-size:10px'>Quantity</th>"
                + "<th style='border-bottom-style:dotted;border-bottom-width:1px;font-size:10px'>Price</th>"
                + "<th style='border-bottom-style:dotted;border-bottom-width:1px;font-size:10px'>Status</th>"
                + "</tr>";
    $(rowHead).appendTo(thead);

    // ASP.NET encapsulates JSON responses in a property "d"
    if (data.hasOwnProperty("d")) 
    { 
        data = data.d;     
    }

    //iterate through and append to table
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     var rowText = "<tr><td style='text-align: left;font-size:10px;'>" + data[i].Name
        + "</td><td style='text-align: left;font-size:10px;'>" + data[i].Quantity 
        + "</td><td style='text-align: left;font-size:10px;'>" + data[i].Price 
        + "</td><td style='text-align: left;font-size:10px;'>"
        + "<select id=" + data[i].Id + ">"
        + "<option value='Unconfirmed'>UnConfirmed</option>" 
        + "<option value='Confirmed'>Confirmed</option>"
        + "<option value='Suspend'>Suspend</option>"
        + "</select></td></tr>";
        $(rowText).appendTo(tbody);

        } 
}
```

How do I bind the field Status' (data[i].Status) value from the database to the select tag.  The user can toggle this value, but the default value should bind to the value from the database.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: you really need to rethink how you are doing this, it is so messy, you should not be writing out so much html with JS in this way. Consider an MVC approach using a template and a template render

Comment: It's not a good approach but you can test `data[i].Status` with your statuses and set `selected` to the `select`

Comment: What do you mean by "binding a select tag" ? You mean, link it with something ? fill it ? modify it ? It's not clear.

Comment: I want to display the correct status. Right now it just defaults to the first option value 'Unconfirmed'.  I want the select tag to show the value from the database (which could be any one of those three 'Unconfirmed', 'Confirmed' or 'Suspend')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight forward way to do this is to do this.

```
    + "<option value='Unconfirmed'"+(data[i].Status == "Unconfirmed"?" selected":"")+">UnConfirmed</option>" 
    + "<option value='Confirmed'"+(data[i].Status == "Confirmed"?" selected":"")+">Confirmed</option>"
    + "<option value='Suspend'"+(data[i].Status == "Suspend"?" selected":"")+">Suspend</option>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the corresponding part of your code with something like this (if I'm understanding your need correctly):

```
for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
  var options = {"unconfirmed":"","confirmed":"","suspend":""};
  options[data[i].Status] = "selected";
  ...
  + "<option value='Unconfirmed' "+options.unconfirmed+">UnConfirmed</option>"
  + "<option value='Confirmed' "+options.confirmed+">Confirmed</option>"
  + "<option value='Suspend' "+options.suspend+">Suspend</option>"
  ...
}
```